# certbot (Let’s Encrypt) for local domain NXDOMAIN looking up A for **.domain

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, https, certbot

I am trying to use [`certbot`](https://certbot.eff.org) ([Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)) for a local domain.

In `/etc/hosts` I have this.

```
127.0.0.1       myapp.whitebear.com
```

But when I run `certbot` (Let’s Encrypt) shows this error.

How can I set the HTTPS for for a localhost?

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for myapp.whitebear.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain myapp.whitebear.com
http-01 challenge for myapp.whitebear.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: myapp.whitebear.com
   Type:   dns
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for myapp.whitebear.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Let’s Encrypt certificates your domain has to exist in the DNS system. Local overrides such as `/etc/hosts` will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much, sooo what is the best practice to use https on Localhost?? some services (ex facebook login) needs to be https..

Comment: I found https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert I will try to use this.

Comment: _Just a thought_: Is it a possible solution to make these local domains public available [with a public IP] and allow the access in `.htaccess` only from my private network [where I know the IP addresses]. In other words, `certbot` and `Let's Encrypt` must **NOT** access these domains in the usual way as browser do - e.q. through port 80 & 443.

Comment: @AlBundy, you can validate a domain via just DNS records, it doesn't have to point to hosted website.  The domain just has to exist in the public DNS system and you have to have control over it.  If you are going to use http base validation though then Let's Encrypt must be able to make it's HTTP requests so you can't block it in anyway.